# Update the multiple value and display using AngularJS and laravel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

```
[{"user_id":78936,"social_id":null,"type":2,"name":"Get Raj","first_name":"Get","last_name":"Raj","email":"test1@yopmail.com"},

{"user_id":78937,"social_id":null,"type":2,"name":"James thomas","first_name":"James","last_name":"thomas","email":"jamesthoms@yopmail.com"}] 

<div ng-repeat="user in profiles">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-ie-5">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="entry_{{user.user_id}}"
      ng-model="update.entry"
      ng-change="save(user, update)"
      >
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-ie-5">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="info_{{user.user_id}}"
      ng-model="update.info"
      ng-change="save(user, update)"
      >
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-ie-5">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="textual_{{user.user_id}}"
      ng-model="update.textual"
      ng-change="save(user, update)"
      >
    </div>          
</div>


function makeOrderItemUrl(user_id, order_id){
       return 'v1/update/' + user_id + '/order_id/' + order_id;
    }

$scope.save = function (person, update) {


     var person = person;
     var order = null,
     matchCount = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.order.items.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.order.items[i].user_id == person.user_id) {
                  order = $scope.order.items[i];
                  matchCount++;
                }
              }

      if(order){
          $http.post(makeOrderItemUrl(person.user_id, order.order_id), update)
          .success(function(res){
            $scope.update = res.data;
          }).error(function () {
            notify.message('There was an issue saving your changes, please try again later.');
          });  
      }

    };
```

Since we have two users so we will get twice input fields i.e ng-model="update.entry" two times then whenever I type in the first textbox it get reflected the same value in the second textbox as well because of the same model they are using how can I set different models and value to be saved into the database and display respectively.

```
Laravel 

$orderItem =  OrderItem::firstOrNew([
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'order_id' => $order_id
                    ]); 

if($orderItem->exists){
            $orderItem->entry = Input::get('entry');    
            $orderItem->save();
        }
```

//This is working fine but it's hard to display.

Answer (score 0):

Make `update` a deeper object where the user id's are used as first level keys

```
<input
      type="text"
      name="entry_{{user.user_id}}"
      ng-model="update[user.user_id].entry"
      ng-change="save(user, update[user.user_id])"
      >
```

Then `$scope.update` would look like:

```
{
  id1: {
    textual: '...',
    entry: '...',
    info: '...'
  },
  id2: {
    textual: '...',
    entry: '...',
    info: '...'
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to write more than 1 character for second user

Comment: for the entry field

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces it. Also make sure to define `$scope.update` as an object in controller and add `track by index` to `ng-repeat`

Comment: $http.get(getinfo(order_id))
          .success(function(res){
            $scope.orderItems[currentuser.user_id] = res.data;
          }).error(function (){
            notify.message('There was an issue, please try again later.');
          });

Comment: Getting Object {
            user_id: "78936", entry: "64"
          }

Comment: how to bind above object to html, Values are not showing into textboxes pls guide

Comment: Make a plunker demo...or use any other sandbox like jsfiddle or codepen. Hard to help without a [mcve]